# Actionbar Sherlock Change Title Color

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock, android-theme

I am trying the Theme Sherlock Action Bar. I want to set the color of the Title as White. When i try to do the following the Title disappears all together.

Also I want to change the background color of an Action Item Icon when Pressed.

What i have tried ?

```
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <!-- Variation on the Holo Light theme that styles the Action Bar -->
    <style name="Theme.Nomad" parent="Theme.Sherlock.Light">
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.Nomad.ActionBar</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.Nomad.ActionBar</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarItemBackground">@drawable/actionbar_selectable_background</item>
        <item name="actionBarItemBackground">@drawable/actionbar_selectable_background</item>
        <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/TitleText</item>
        <item name="titleTextStyle">@style/TitleText</item>

        <!--
        <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/MyPopupMenu</item>
        <item name="popupMenuStyle">@style/MyPopupMenu</item>

        <item name="android:dropDownListViewStyle">@style/MyDropDownListView</item>
        <item name="dropDownListViewStyle">@style/MyDropDownListView</item>

        <item name="android:actionBarTabStyle">@style/MyActionBarTabStyle</item>
        <item name="actionBarTabStyle">@style/MyActionBarTabStyle</item>

        <item name="android:actionDropDownStyle">@style/MyDropDownNav</item>
        <item name="actionDropDownStyle">@style/MyDropDownNav</item>

        <item name="android:listChoiceIndicatorMultiple">@drawable/ad_btn_check_holo_light</item>
        <item name="android:listChoiceIndicatorSingle">@drawable/ad_btn_radio_holo_light</item>

        <item name="android:actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/MyOverflowButton</item>


        -->
    </style>

    <style name="Widget.Nomad.ActionBar" parent="Widget.Sherlock.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">#E5492A</item>
        <item name="background">#E5492A</item>
    </style>

    <style name="TitleText" parent="TextAppearance.Sherlock.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
        <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
        <item name="textColor">@android:color/white</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">18dip</item>
        <item name="textSize">18dip</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am not sure about item background, but for text color you can:

- add these items in Widget.Nomad.ActionBar (style with parent Widget.Sherlock.ActionBar):

  ```
  <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/TitleText</item>
  <item name="titleTextStyle">@style/TitleText</item>
  ```
- where:

  ```
  <style name="TitleText" parent="TextAppearance.Sherlock.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
      <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
      <item name="android:textSize">18sp</item>
  </style>
  ```

Comment: i have added that. But it doesnt help :(

Comment: I know you can write an xml file that defines drawable states for your action item (and add it as the item's background), like for any other button, but I am not sure is there any  way to do this using action bar style

Comment: Try moving titleTextStyle and android:titleTextStyle in Widget.Nomad.ActionBar

Comment: they should be attributes of Widget.Nomad.ActionBar

Comment: sorry i got confused where to move it. thank you. i got it working :D

Comment: @Tamara Your comment about titleTextStyle being part of the actionbar style was what was tripping me up. I recommend putting that into the answer for people who skip over comments.

Comment: Hi I did this:

<style name="Widget.Nomad.ActionBar" parent="Widget.Sherlock.ActionBar"><item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/TitleText</item> <item name ="titleTextStyle">@style/TitleText</item>
    
Am I doing this right? How do I link it to the overall theme I use for the app?

Answer (score 4):

The best solution is this!

```
actionBar.setTitle(Html.fromHtml("<font color=\"#ffffff\"><b>" + AppName + "</b></font>"));
```

I promise it will be very helpful! Good luck!